# WP User Frontend Pro

Tags: wordpress

We have a custom posttype and for displaying that we use very customised template files.

As we use WP User Frontend Pro, we want to check inside the tmemplate (by php/function..) if the user who is currently viewing the page has an active subscription to subscription pack with ID (whatever).
Is tha possbile somehow? Like:

```
if $user->has_subscription($id) => "GO4GOLD";
if NOT => "Adios";
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: I'd suggest you need to lookup the wordpress API for user roles and capabilities ( https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/ ) - it should support what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

By default, WP User Frontend paid version allows restriction with subscription pack. So when your user is not subscribed to a particular subscription pack, he will not be able to view the page.

Please check the screenshot [here](https://prnt.sc/syccy7).